# how to get datetime value from gridcolumn?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, devexpress, filtering

how do i get the datetime value, because i think the problem here is the repository value was a string not a date value

1. my grid column

[image]

2. for repository item combobox

[image]

3. when i select it, i can filter because the value was string, the proof was in filter control panel the operand was `Begins with` it should be `equal`

[image]

4. the problem is when i filter by control panel, i cant be filter

[image]

5. output by filter control

[image]

for code:

```
    RepositoryItemComboBox repositoryItemComboBox1 = new RepositoryItemComboBox();

    ci.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss tt";

private void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView view = sender as GridView;
    for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
    {
      if (gridView1.GetDataRow(i) == null)
      {
        break;
      }

    DateTime signIn1 = Convert.ToDateTime(gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["signIn"]);
    DateTime signIn_md = Convert.ToDateTime(signIn1.ToString(ci.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern));

      if (!repositoryItemComboBox1.Items.Contains(signIn_md))
      {
         repositoryItemComboBox1.Items.Add(signIn_md);
      }

    }
      if (e.Column.FieldName == "signIn" && view.IsFilterRow(e.RowHandle))
      {
      e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemComboBox1;
      repositoryItemComboBox1.Sorted = true;    
      }
}


private void filterControl1_BeforeShowValueEditor(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Filtering.ShowValueEditorEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.CurrentNode.Property.Name == "signIn")
            {
                e.CustomRepositoryItem = repositoryItemComboBox9;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to convert a string to DateTime.

```
string strDate = "01 Aug 2016 15:31:07 PM";
DateTime dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(strDate);
```

Comment: but it's kinda troublesome if i add manual, isnt it the same with my code ?
i think the problem was the filter control

Answer (score 0):

Why are you converting your input to `DateTime` two times? Apparently there is some bug right here:

```
DateTime signIn1 = Convert.ToDateTime(gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["signIn"]);
DateTime signIn_md = Convert.ToDateTime(signIn1.ToString(ci.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern));
```

Maybe you should use `DateTime.ParseExact` for that? Since you know what exactly is the desired format, you can replace it all with something like that:

```
DateTime signIn_md = DateTime.ParseExact(gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["signIn"], new String[] { "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss tt" }, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: also i think the problem was in filter control, since it read time 00:00:00 am